# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on value type c#

Tags: c#, string, int

I wrote two lines of code

1)

```
int i ;
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

2)

```
string str;
MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
```

As I didn't initialize any of the variables and (1) is returning `0` but (2) throws an exception saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I can't understand that string is value type as int then this error is being shown.

Comment: I think second snippet should be `MessageBox.Show(str);`?

Comment: yes it's MessageBox.Show(str);

Comment: in snippet str is itself a string so no need to do `str.ToString();`. `MessageBox.Show(str);` would suffice?

Answer (score 3):

`....I can't understand that string is value type as int then this error is being occurred.`

Who said string is value type? Its **reference** type and you have to give its value before using it, other wise you will get the error you are getting.

Whereas int is value type. Even if you do not initialize it, the are initialized by 0.

You can do this

```
string str = String.Empty; 

str = SomeFunctionReturningString();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) //cause that function can also return null.
    MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Comment: like string is there any data type as reference type?

Comment: if I declare string and assign a value for for different five times.
so there will five objects or only one object will be overwritten.

Comment: The latter. The last one will be retained.

Comment: what's mean by "last one will be retained"?
.
there will be five objects or a single object will be overwritten?

Comment: if you put "I", then "We", then "A" so "A" will be in the variable. "We" will overwrite "I" and "A" will overwrite "We".

Comment: mean there will be single object.
Thanks.

Comment: When you assign a string variable a new value, new string data is created that is completely separate from the original. The original string will remain in memory. If there's no remaining reference the string can be removed when garbage collection occurs. This is almost the same as for any other reference type. However, string interning means that it's possible for two independently created, matching strings to use the same underlying memory to store the data. It's not the case that assigning a new string value to a string variable will overwrite the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a value type, and `string` is a reference type, so they are different.

When you have a **field** (class-level variable), and you don't initialize the field value where you declare the field, then an `int` will be initialized with its default value which is `0`. And a `string` field will get the default *value* of a reference type, which is the `null` reference.

When you have a **local variable**, you must assign a value to it before you use it. A local variable is one that is declared in the body of a method (or constructor, accessor etc.). Therefore your question was confusing, because it was not clear if you had fields or locals.